# How to render an ejs file after an action occured in loopback

Tags: node.js, express, loopbackjs

I need to render an ejs file after updating some contents to db in loopback model js file

**Sample code**

```
Inviteduser.inviteStatusConfirm = function (invitedUserId, callback) {
var status = 2;
 Inviteduser.upsert({
   id: invitedUserId,
   confirm: status
 }, (err, res) => {
 if (err) {
  callback(err)
 } else {
   return succ.render(path.resolve(__dirname, '../../server/views/invitation-success.ejs'), {});
 }
});
};
```

I can't render invitation-success.ejs file.

Answer (score 0):

What is succ in this context? That should be something in the line of

```
app.post('/inviteStatusConfirm', (req, res) => {
   Inviteduser.inviteStatusConfirm(req.body.invitedUserId, (err, value) => {
       if(err) return res.sendStatus(400);
       return res.render('invitation-success', {});
   }
}
```

You need to perform your function and with the callback function result you render your ejs page.

Comment: You need to modify your code to specify what the callback function is. According to your function you can have an error, and a response from the upsert function callback. So that would be a good place to start. [Look at this explanation of how to create your own callback function](https://codeburst.io/javascript-what-the-heck-is-a-callback-aba4da2deced)